# Select-form, make the option stay selected after submit

Tags: php, select, input, while-loop, echo

I have this form:

```
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
    <select name="taskOption" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose group</option>

    <?php

    while($hej < count($hejsan)) {
        echo '<option value=' . $hej . '>' . $hejsan[$hej] . '</option>';
        $hej++;
    }

    ?>

    </select>


    <input type="submit" value="Find bookings">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

When I press the submit button the select/option will reset to the default, how can I change this and make it stay as the one I selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> ```
>  if (isset($_POST['taskOption'])) {
>     $Option = $_POST['taskOption'];
>    }
> while($hej < count($hejsan)) {
>         if($hej==$_POST['taskOption']){
>            $selected = "selected=selected";
>          }else{
>            $selected = "";
>          }
>     echo '<option value="' . $hej . '" '.$selected .'>' . $hejsan[$hej] . '</option>';
>     $hej++;
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, got a bit confused first because my page went blank when I tried it, but you forgot a ')'. It should say   if(isset($_POST['taskOption']))

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look at the option you have selected and make the corresponding option `selected`. Since your form leads to the same page, you can just look at the contents of `$_POST`.

P.S.: also, you will find it useful to echo a newline after each option to make the output more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$taskOption = '';
if (isset($_POST['taskOption']) {
  $taskOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
}
?>
<form method="post">
<fieldset>
    <select name="taskOption" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose group</option>

    <?php

    while($hej < count($hejsan)) {
        if ($hey == $taskOption) {
            echo "<option value={$hey} selected>{$hejsan[$hej]}</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value={$hey}>{$hejsan[$hej]}</option>";
        }
        $hej++;
    }

    ?>

    </select>


    <input type="submit" value="Find bookings">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a if else statement to it. If the option value is equal to the select, then add the selected="selected"

This is an example code. could be that the operator is wrong, im always confused with the greater then and smaller then operators.

```
<?php

$option_value = 5;

for($i=0; $i > 10; $i++){
    if($option_value == 5){
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'" selected="selected">Item number'.$i.' is selected</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">Item number'.$i.'</option>';
    }
}


?>
```